# Create Excel Spread Sheet with different section in a tab with each section having a vertical scrollbar

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, excel-2010, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am a beginner to Excel. I am using Excel 2010. I am trying to create an excel spread sheet that has different sections. For example Lets say, my sheet tab is labeled sports. I want the sheet to have different section of sports like basketball, baseball, and football all on the same sheet.  In Each section I want to have a like 5 columns with a vertical and or horizontal scroll bar. Is this possible to have?

Comment: why do you need scrolling within each section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to go into the View tab on the ribbon, use the "New Window" button to make new windows, and then Arrange those windows.

The data can all be in one sheet or in multiple sheets, but you should be able to view all at the same time, with individual scroll bars.

I would actually strongly recommend storing each sport in it's own separate sheet, because while you can freeze panes separately in each window, you cannot hide columns separately.

I'm not exactly sure what you're aiming for here though.

And when it looks how you want it to, you'll want to save your workspace.